# Multiple instances of a ScriptManager

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajax

I have a master page and hundreds of content pages. Every content page contains `ToolKitScript Manager` for every `UpdatePanel`s on each content page. Right now, I want to add `Script Manager` on the master page and when I try to execute, error shows `"Only one instance of a ScriptManager can be added to the page."` So I comment/remove every `ToolKitScript` line on each content page. What I want to ask, is there any solution so I don't have to comment/remove every single line of code on my hundreds of content page?

Here is the following code on every single content pages which I have to remove one by one.

```
<AjaxControl:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></AjaxControl:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

Here is the following code on my master page which I have to add.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManagerNotif" runat="server" >
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/js/jquery-1.2.6.js" />
        </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could only have one ScriptManager and ToolkitScriptManager comes with Ajax tool kit, which is a later version of ScriptManager. therefore if you use ToolkitScriptManager instead of the ScriptManager in your Master page it should work fine. You don't need ToolkitScriptManager in each content page then.